# Default to New Record when opening Form - Access

Tags: ms-access

When opening a Form I would like it default to a blank record for data entry.

I tried changing "Data Entry" to "Yes" but I would still like to view other records.

How can I open a Form and have it default to a New/Blank Record but still allow me to go through other records?

Comment: Use `GoToRecord` macro command to form `On Open` event.

Comment: Or in VBA, `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`

Comment: "The DataEntry property has an effect only when the AllowAdditions property is set to Yes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form load event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```